# Is DataFrame schema saved when using parquet format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

If one calls `df.write.parquet(destination)`, is the DataFrame schema (i.e. `StructType` information) saved along with the data?

If the parquet files are generated by other programs other than Spark, how does `sqlContext.read.parquet` figure out the schema of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parquet](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) files automatically preserves the schema of the original data when saving. So there will be no difference if it's Spark or another system that writes/reads the data.

---

If one or multiple columns are used to partition the data when saving, the data type for these columns are lost (since the information is stored in the file structure). The data types of these can be automatically inferred by Spark when reading (currently only numeric data types and strings are supported).

This automatic inference can be turned off by setting `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` to false, which will make these columns be read as strings. For more information see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery).

Comment: Not if the dataset is empty. Is there a way to save the schema, if the dataset is empty?

Comment: @Midiparse: This is a known issue that seems to have been fixed in Spark version 2.4.0. Link to JIRA issue + possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821408/saving-empty-dataframe-with-known-schema-spark-2-2-1